# Анимация вокруг круга

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, анимация, css-animation

Как я могу сделать такую анимацию вокруг круга?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такую анимацию можно сделать с помощью CSS и правила `@keyframes`, установив общие ключевые кадры. Эффект свечения можно получить с помощью свойства `blur`. Кроме этого, нам необходимо в общем контейнере использовать несколько дополнительных строчных элементов `span`, так как в нашей фигуре используется ряд элементов. Вот пример того, что у нас получилось:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, green, red);
  animation: animate 0.5s linear infinite;
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}

.circle span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, green, red);
}

.circle span:nth-child(1) {filter: blur(5px);}
.circle span:nth-child(2) {filter: blur(10px);}
.circle span:nth-child(3) {filter: blur(20px);}
.circle span:nth-child(4) {filter: blur(40px);}

@keyframes animate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

Чтобы сделать эффект анимации более интересным, дополнительно по той же аналогии мы можем анимировать и центральный круг, запустив анимацию в обратную сторону. Вот пример:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

.wrp {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, gold, orangered);
  animation: animate 1.0s linear infinite;
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}

.circle__center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, darkgray 50%, black 100%);
  animation: animate__return 1.0s linear infinite;
}

.circle span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, gold, orangered);
}

.circle span:nth-child(1) {filter: blur(5px);}
.circle span:nth-child(2) {filter: blur(10px);}
.circle span:nth-child(3) {filter: blur(20px);}
.circle span:nth-child(4) {filter: blur(40px);}

@keyframes animate {
  0% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
@keyframes animate__return {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
<div class="circle">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div class="circle__center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Вот такая крутилка на svg, вероятно, подойдет:

```css
circle {
  animation: rot 10s infinite linear;
} 

@keyframes rot {
  0% {transform:rotate(0)}
  100% {transform:rotate(1turn)}
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-250 -250 500 500" style="background:black" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="radial">
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="transparent"/>
      <stop offset="40.5%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="45%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="55%" stop-color="transparent"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <mask id="mask">
      <circle fill="url(#radial)" r="400"/>
    </mask>
    <linearGradient id="linear">
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="blue"/>
      <stop offset="45%" stop-color="green"/>
      <stop offset="55%" stop-color="green"/>
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="red"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle mask="url(#mask)" r="400" fill="url(#linear)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

А потом еще подумал и сделал на css

```css
body {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  animation: rot 10s infinite linear;
  border:solid;
  background: 
        radial-gradient(circle at center, #000, #000 50%, #0000 51%, #0000 55%, #000 66%), 
        linear-gradient(red 20%, green 45%, green 55%, blue 80%)
    
} 

@keyframes rot {
  0% {transform:rotate(0)}
  100% {transform:rotate(1turn)}
}
```

```html
<div/>
```